# Avoiding Unit parameter declaration when implementing generic interface

Tags: kotlin, syntax

I have an interface `Handler<T>` with one method `handle(item: T)`  and some classes implementing it:

```
class FooHandler : Handler<String>
class BarHandler : Handler<Int>
class BazHandler : Handler<Unit>
```

In the last one, `handle` implementation looks like this:

```
override fun handle(nothing: Unit) {
  //whatever
}
```

I find it quite ugly. It would be great Kotlin allow to avoid parameter declaration when it is of type `Unit`, like:

```
override fun handle() {
  //whatever
}
```

But it's not supported so far. Does Kotlin have something to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your interface looks like this:

```
interface Handler<T> {
  fun handle(item: T)
}
```

You could wrap it in another interface like this:

```
interface TypelessHandler : Handler<Unit> {
  fun handle()

  override fun handle(item: Unit) {
    handle()
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
class FooHandler: TypelessHandler {
  override fun handle() {
    //whatever
  }
}
```